# ezdxf and Matplotlib how to increase line thickness

Tags: python, matplotlib, line, ezdxf

I'm converting a DXF file to a PNG below, but I want to increase the `line` thickness.

The lines right now are approximately 1 pixel wide right now, I want to be able to make them 5 times as big.

I've tried soloutions from diffrent places like:

```py
mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 5  # set the value globally
mpl.rcParams['patch.linewidth'] = 5  # set the value globally
mpl.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 5  # set the value globally
mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 5  # set the value globally
```

A list of other soloutions i've tried:

```py
1. 
fig = plt.figure(linewidth=5)

2.
for ln in ax.lines:
    ln.set_linewidth(5)

3.
for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(5)
4. 
[i.set_linewidth(5) for i in ax.spines.itervalues()]
```

But I got nothing to work properly.

Here's a working example:

main.py

```py
from ezdxf.addons.drawing.matplotlib import MatplotlibBackend
from ezdxf.addons.drawing import Frontend, RenderContext
import ezdxf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 5  # set the value globally
mpl.rcParams['patch.linewidth'] = 5  # set the value globally
mpl.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 5  # set the value globally
mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 5  # set the value globally


dxffilepath = 'GT-001.DXF'
save_to = 'test.png'


def convert_dxf2img(path, save_to, img_format, img_res):
    doc = ezdxf.readfile(path)
    msp = doc.modelspace()
    auditor = doc.audit()

    if len(auditor.errors) != 0:
        return
    else:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
        ctx = RenderContext(doc)
        ctx.set_current_layout(msp)
        ctx.current_layout.set_colors(bg='#FFFFFF')

        out = MatplotlibBackend(ax)
        Frontend(ctx, out).draw_layout(msp, finalize=True)

        fig.savefig(save_to, dpi=img_res)
        plt.close(fig)

convert_dxf2img(dxffilepath, save_to, img_format='.png', img_res=300)
```

The lines are to thin, I want to make them 5 times as thick. Is there any way to do that?

Output I get:
[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extended control of the backend will be possible in the next version of ezdxf v0.15, stable alpha versions already available at [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ezdxf/#history).

Scale the lineweight by a factor of 5:

```
    ...
    out = MatplotlibBackend(ax, params={"lineweight_scaling": 5})
    ...
```

More backend options are documented [here](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/addons/drawing.html) and the `params` argument is also supported by the `qsave()` function.

Comment: I get the following error: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'params'`

Comment: Be sure you use a pre-release version of ezdxf: `pip install ezdxf==0.15a3`

Comment: Yep, I tried to use `a0`, didn't work, so i tried `a3` just as you said it, and it works perfectly! Thank you so much for the help!